# What is Noita downloading every time I quit the game?

Tags: steam, noita

Every time I quit the game, a small file downloads extremely slowly.  I get less than 1kb/s on that download for some reason, even though I normally get 100mb/s or better.  This is a problem because I can't play anything else while it downloads; so when my friends invite me to play something else, they have to wait for me.

What is going on here, and can I fix it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By default, Steam will sync your save games every time the game exits. You can disable this easily:

1. Right-click the game in the library and click "Properties".
2. Go to the "Updates" tab.
3. Uncheck "Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for Noita.

For some reason the cloud synchronization is really slow for this game. That is something you probably can't fix; you might want to take it up with the developers or Valve. It could have something to do with there being an unusually large amount of files within LocalLow/Nolla_Games_Noita/save00 - 451 in my case.

Comment: Lots of small files usually means a slow sync, even on a decent connection. I don't know if it's still the case, but steam sync also sync's every '*save*' file, every time, even if not recently changed. PITA when you have lots (80+) of saves in skyrim or something similarly large.

Comment: Something that worked in The Witcher 1 and 2 was to copy all the old save files out into a different folder to keep them backed up but to not need to sync them with steam every time the game saved.

Comment: Yup, this is a design flaw. Not something you can fix from the consumer-end.

Comment: I also noticed that the upload speed for saves seems to be capped by design. Skyrim save game can become pretty big (30mb~ isn't rare), but even though it is only two files, the uploadspeed usually does not reach higher than 10kb/s~. (my upload is around 500mb/s, so that is clearly not the issue)